# Skrollr parallax breaks when resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax, skrollr

I'm working on this site http://andreas-berg.dk/wordpress/ - inside the section with all the hexagones, I have set up a parallax effect on the background image. Right here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/swi9zab8nn5l1hj/Screenshot%202014-04-14%2010.12.22.png

If your browser window is maxed out there's nothing, but as soon as you're resizing the window, at little as 1 pixel, the background image gets pushed down. Any idea what's causing this to happen? It works fine if I resize it, refresh the browser, but that would be stupid to do everything the browser is resized and not user friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me in FireFox on mac, could you specify what browser you are using?
Had to add answer instead of comment due to lack of reputation :)

Comment: Oh sure, I'm using Chrome on Mac :) it also jumps down when I'm browsing with Firefox here though.

Comment: Seems to work fine there as well, do you have the latest version of chrome?

Comment: I have, yes :) looks like I made it work by writing a window load function before init Skrollr.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that I fixed by destroying skrollr and rerunning .init() on window resize.  It created a lot of extra space on the bottom of my body unless I added forceHeight:false to it.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  skroll.destroy();
  skroll = skrollr.init({forceHeight: false});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add following code to end of your parallax.js

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].onresize = function() {
setTimeout(function(){
    jQuery(window).trigger('resize').trigger('scroll');
}, 100);};
```